# Which Helvetica Neue font to install for sites?

Tags: fonts, css

I see `Helvetica` and `Helvetica Neue` in the CSS for some sites yet I don't know which one of the many Helvetica/Helvetice Neue fonts the site *intended* to use.

I have bought the pack of Helvetica fonts but after installing all of them the site seems to pick the bold and oblique one at random which makes the text look extremely unreadable.

Which font is the intended one?

Comment: Macs come with Helvetica, which is why many websites call for it instead of Arial.

Comment: But Helvetica refers to a font-family with a variety of different fonts. Which one is considered the *default* among them?